# Jquery nth-child getting unexpected elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Having some trouble with JQuery's nth-child and hoping someone can spot my error.

My HTML is kind of like this

```
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRow" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: none;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRow" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: none;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRow" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: none;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRow" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: none;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRow" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: none;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRow" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: none;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: block;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: block;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: block;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: block;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: block;">
<div class="suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly" style="width: 32%; margin-right: 1%; float: left; display: block;">
```

What I'm trying to do is every 4th element is add the css clear: left.

If I do

```
$('.suggestedContentAmountRow:nth-child(4n)').css({"clear": "left"});
$('.suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly:nth-child(4n)').css({"clear": "left"});
```

for suggestedContentAmountRow is works fine. For suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly though it is selecting the 2nd and 6th element (looks like just counting the 4th from where suggestedContentAmountRow left off). So what should I be using instead of nth-child?

edit: While this time there 6 elements for each class, sometimes it will be more. Generally don't want just the 4th element as with 9 I will want the 4th and 7th or sometimes might want every 2nd so eq won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no current way in css to do it, though it will get there at some point in the future...

Saying that, it is possible in one small piece of jQuery -

```
$('.suggestedContentAmountRow').filter(function(i) {
    return !(i % 4);
}).css({"clear": "left"});
$('.suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly').filter(function(i) {
    return !(i % 4);
}).css({"clear": "left"});
```

Use the filter method to only pass ones that have a modulus 4 (ie, no remainder when divided by 4). You cannot put them both into a single selector as it's the result from the selector that needs the filtering, and it would give the same incorrect results as the css.

-- edit

As a slight "improvement", you can make it into an easier single method -

```
$.fn.every4th = function() {
    return this.filter(function(i) {
        return !(i % 4);
    });
};

$('.suggestedContentAmountRow').every4th().css({"clear": "left"});
$('.suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly').every4th().css({"clear": "left"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Childs in CSS are counted since the parent element. So doesn't matter how classnames you are define. The way to achieve this with css is wrapping the second group of elements into a parent.

With jQuery yes, you can, but not with the CSS selector that have the behaviour that I tell you in the first paragraph. You can make this:

```
$('.suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly').get(4)
```

Be careful, because it returns a DOM object and not a jQuery object. You can *jqueryfy* it like this:

```
var DOMobj = $('.suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly').get(4);
var jQueryObj = $(DOMobj);
```

Good luck

### EDIT

As Rycochet said in the comments, you can use `eq()` function to return a jquery object directly:

```
$('.suggestedContentAmountRowMonthly').eq(4).css({clear:'left'});
```

Comment: Just use ```.eq(4)``` instead of ```.get(4)``` to get a new jQuery object rather than a DOM element...

Comment: I didn't know this function, I was thinking that `eq` was a selector (like `$('.class:eq(2)')` . But taking a look to the API it seems to work. I edit my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I should have specificed more but I need every x element as sometimes will need to select more than just 1 from the class. Example if have 9 elements would need the 4th and 7th so have the clear: left.

Though with the info that child looks at the parent and not the class name, can solve this by just wrapping the classes in another div.